# PHP SimpleXMLElement load XML with xmlns

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to load an XML file from a URL using SimpleXMLElement.

My code basically looks like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
```

$url is the string of the URL containing XML response. I can load it just fine if there is no "xmlns" in the XML. When there is "xmlns", it'll cause runtime error:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: http://test.cloudapp.net:8080/api/missiondetails/1:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/test.com/test.php on line 10
```

This is the example of the XML format:

```
<MissionDetails xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.DataTransferObject"></Mission>
```

Anybody knows how to load XML with "xmlns" in the root node?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The error is not caused by `"xmlns"`, so it is just a coincidence you mention here, not the cause of the error. You do find the cause of the error in it's message. Which part of the error message is hard for you to understand?

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using? The `data_is_url` (3rd) argument for the `SimpleXMLElement` constructor was only added in 5.1.2.

Also, the second argument should be an integer, `0` by default.

Perhaps try using [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.simplexml-load-file.php) instead